# Drupal 7: Contextual Filter for Second URL Argument (taxonomy term)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Hurting my brain trying to get this to work, maybe someone can help me out.

I have products, each product has a family.  The path-auto url is {product family}/{product name}

Each product has a family relation, meaning you can select its' parent via a taxonomy term.

On the product family page I'd like a rundown of the available products.  I've tried to use contextual filters but every Google result's method isn't working, so I finally came here looking for help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, scratch that.  It seems that the Preview functionality just doesn't work the way it should.

I took my chances and enabled the block, there it was.